# Content folder not being recognised in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, css, asp.net-mvc

I started a new "Basic" project in MVC 4. When it came to styling, my css file in the Content folder is not being picked up.

I have included the link href etc in the _layout.cshtml file and still nothing is happening.

When I move the css file into say the Controllers folder and change the path in my _layout.cshtml file, the styling is applied.

Has anyone else had this problem?

I have tried the following in the _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in the CSS file:

```
body{ background-color:Blue; }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what your style tag looks like?

Comment: <link href="~/Content/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> should work

Comment: fwiw, stick with using `@Url.Content()` and get rid of the relative references.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define base href on _Layout.cshtml somthing like this

```
<base href="YoursiteDomain" />
```

So all your static content (i.e. css,images and js which are in content folder) can be rnder with this base href.

Note : You have to place it in the top of head section before defining css or other static contents.

if this is not works then definitely this is the iis problem.

You can try then via switching application pool in iis from integrated to classic mode.

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Main.css")" rel="stylesheet"  />
```

This should work fine assuming that you have a css file called `Main.css` in your `Content` folder which is in the root.

The one which Visual studio (2012) create is called **Site.css**, not **Main.css**. So double check that the name of your css file match with the path you provide in the layout page.